# Trial function in variational principle - why do we choose this ansatz?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, variational-principle, non-linear-systems, non-linear-optics

I am reading [this](http://www.phys.umu.se/plasma/nonlinear/First-variational.pdf) paper right now and I cannot understand the intuition behind their choice of ansatz in the variational 
principle.

Specifically this passage on the second page of the paper puzzles me:  [image]

What motivates this choice of trial function? 
My guess is, that we know solitons to be of the form $$A_s(z,t)=A_0\; \text{sech}(\frac{t}{\tau})\;e^{-j\theta}$$ where $\theta$ is the nonlinear phase shift of the soliton. Thus, the trial function has a similar shape to the solution of the NLS eq. However, I do not understand the reasoning beyond this fact to choose the above trial function.

Comment: Often a "natural choice" comes from knowing the solution (often the full analytic solution) to a simpler related problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is why I looked as soliton solutions of other nonlinear problems. However, this alone seems to be a rather flimsy explanation of why this specific ansatz was chosen.